# "add comment" link disappears after voting to close a question as off topic with custom comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, vote-to-close

Simple to reproduce: (**note: only non moderator 3K+ users can reproduce**)

1. Go to a question.
2. Cast a close vote as off topic choose Other and put custom comment. Confirm.
3. The custom comment is added and the "add comment" link disappears.

After refresh the link appears as usual.

For what it's worth, Chrome 28.0.1500.72 here but I'm 99.999% sure it's not related to browser.

<strike>Sometimes there is no "add comment" link at all even after many reloads. When it happens I noticed additional request to the server which doesn't appear when the link is present: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/190301/comments so this leads me to believe that on certain condition which I can't reproduce, the whole comments placeholder is replaced with the result of that request, and indeed there's no "add comment" link there.</strike>
Didn't happen, guess that one was fixed.

Comment: Yup reproduced here on this very question, lol! :)

Comment: Success, flagged your question and added comment.

Comment: @Azik do you mean the link doesn't disappear after flagging?

Comment: @Shadow wizard, reproduced ?!

Comment: yes the link doesn't disappear after flagging?

Comment: And no one cares to give browser details? Oh really...

Comment: @GrantThomas doubt it's browser specific, but will add anyhow.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome 22.0.1229.79, and FF 22.

Comment: I noticed "add comment" disappearing basically just everywhere, hmm can't reproduce it on this question but I've seen it disappearing commenting on my own SO answer and on another question on Meta.

Comment: @OldCheckmark yeah, just happened here to me now but after some reloads it's OK.

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to cast the last close vote. Not because I need to test this again, but just for my own amusement.

Comment: @Cody hmm... let me check something. Nope, can't get rid of the close votes. Go ahead, if and when it will be fixed I'm sure the dev can reopen to post his answer. Also worth to check if it happens when casting reopen vote.

Comment: We're looking at it.

Comment: @Tim thanks, see my edit for possible tip in debugging.

Comment: Working on this now...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd is this still a problem?  I haven't been able to reproduce it, but we just built out several fixes related to this.

Comment: @Ben yep still happens. Tried to close an old question and the "add comment" disappeared. (retracted the vote of course) - due to your diamond your vote is binding so the page reloads, you'll have to use 3K+ puppet to test this.

Comment: @Ben I'm also seeing this link disappear when I add a comment (e.g. to one of my own answers here on meta). It also happened on [a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190416/not-an-answer-flags-declined-why/190418?noredirect=1#comment590150_190418), but not *this question*. Evidence: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LNpCG.png

Comment: Also, on questions where I can see the Add Comment link, I'm also sometimes not seeing the Ajax-y "add / show 1 more comment" thingy that slides in when a new comment has been added elsewhere (and I know that it has because I added one in a new window). So something definitely seems funky here.

Comment: And another example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3XJ5x.png

Comment: Is anyone else other than @AaronBertrand still experiencing this issue?

Comment: I'm unable to comment on my own answer. All i did related to that question was downvote the other answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870799/only-get-next-instance-in-the-entire-document

Comment: And, now it's back.

Comment: @Kevin yeah, see the stroked out part in my question... we need to find a way to reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has probably been resolved by fixes for other bugs related to commenting, so I've marked this as [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Update: well....ok.  looking at this some more.

Update 2: this should be fixed in the next build.

Comment: No it's not. You can't reproduce because the page reloads after the actual close, you need ordinary non diamond account with 3K reputation to reproduce.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvOpUJEJ-CM

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Ah, thanks for that.  I think I know what might be causing that.  What browser were you in?

Comment: Latest stable Chrome, but really don't think it's browser specific, there's some JS in action causing it to disappear. :-/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Oh, for sure.  Just wanted to know in case it was relevant.

Comment: Ah, I see.  It's only for off-topic votes where a comment is left.  I'll have to get back to this tomorrow, unfortunately, but now that I know exactly what's happening it shouldn't be a big deal to fix.

Comment: Yep, confirmed, I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Also happening when voting to close as duplicate, even when there's no auto comment added i.e. second vote on a question.

Comment: @BenCollins: Is this really [meta-tag:status-completeed]? I still get this on duplicate closes. The steps I listed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190752/add-comment-disappears-when-voting-to-close-duplicate consistently repos for me.

Comment: @Matt: would you try again?  I can't reproduce using the steps you referenced, but a change related to this was deployed yesterday and may have fixed these issues.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: A related change was deployed yesterday that may have fixed this.  I haven't been able to reproduce.  Can you still do it?

Comment: @Ben can't reproduce, working fine for me.

Comment: @BenCollins: Ditto.

Answer (score 1):

This thing is still disappearing for me on a new question that I haven't voted to close (it's my own)

[image].

Comment: Are you using userscripts?  If you disable them, do you still experience this issue?

Comment: I'll be in [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) off and on.  Try to catch me and we can work through it in realtime.

Comment: @Ben not experiencing it right now but I'll ping you if I spot it again. I've disabled all extensions and userscripts.

Comment: Ok.  I'm going to leave this as [tag:status-norerpo] just to get it out of the open bug list, but certainly hit me up if you see it again.

Comment: Will do, thanks @Ben.

Comment: @Ben [this just happened to me on main SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889830/sql-server-create-evenly-sized-groups). I have the question still open on my screen and can leave it there. [Image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cTiUq.png).

Comment: @Ben it's obviously not an enormous problem, since refreshing gets rid of it, but I figure you folks want to squash it.

Comment: Yep.  there hasn't been a build since I got the fix in , and we're not in a rush at the moment, so you might check again later tonight or maybe even monday.  Like you said - this issue only affects a tiny, tiny number of users and there's a simple workaround, so I'm not in a big rush to push it out.

Comment: @Ben oh ok, I though the fix was already pushed. Thanks.