# Add Comment disappears after editing a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

If I add a comment then edit it and "Save Edits" as soon as I "Save Edits" the add comment hyperlink disappears.  Is this by design?

Comment: same problem as this: ["add comment" link disappears after voting to close a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190301)

Comment: yup. posted [about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190340/225020) at the post Cody Gray mentioned (though wasn't aware of this when I was posting that)

Comment: We're looking at it.

Comment: I'm looking into this right now.  There are several fixes related to this that will deploy soon.

Answer (score 3):

Whoops!  This should be fixed very soon.  I'll update again when it's in an outgoing build.

Update:

This is fixed now.

Comment: Should be working now.

Comment: Let me check... editing... editing again this time clicking... all good!

Comment: Still failing for me.

Comment: @Barmar: make sure you're not getting cached js

Comment: I've tried clearing my cache, it's still happening. I think it even happens when I just add a comment, without editing it.

Comment: Another thing: it doesn't only happen when I've edited a comment. Sometimes it happens just when I add a comment. But it's not consistent.

Comment: I have the same experience as @Barmar, as recently as today. Tough to repro though - every time I record my screen activity, it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make "add comment" disappear (not by voting to close a question though).

Steps to reproduce (suitable for reputation 1 and more on Meta):

1. Click "**add comment**" link.
2. Press enter or click <kbd>Add Comment</kbd>
3. Click "**edit**"
4. Press enter or click <kbd>Save Edit</kbd>
5. ???
6. "**add comment**" link disappears. (see screenshot below)

[image]

Refreshing the page would make it reappear.

I can reproduce this in any post on Meta and SO.

**Browser**: Chrome 28 and IE 10
**OS**: Windows 8

Comment: would you mind moving this to be a separate bug report?

Comment: @Ben [there is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190337/152859). :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: the users are _everywhere_

Comment: @BenCollins, should I move this post to that bug report Shady Wizard linked to?

Comment: @OldCheckmark: If you would.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm someone moved this post here... I got confused for a moment there.

Comment: Yeah, the magic diamond powers! (or even dev only, can't see any trace of merge)