# Not an answer flags declined, why?

Tags: discussion, flags, link-only-answers, not-an-answer

I've flagged the followings as *not an answer*:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6049319/493122
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560748/493122
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3659728/493122
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16661576/493122

And they got declines because:

1. declined - Not everything that contains a link needs to be flagged.
2. declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it
3. declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it
4. declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Now, while I totally agree that not every answer that contains a link needs to be flagged, these are the classical examples of *lazy* answers where the post author takes credit from an external resource that might disappear in the future. And the only text in all these answers is a rephrasing of "See this link". There's not even an hint of an answer in there. It's just a link to an external resource.

When I flag an "answer" as not an answer I ask myself: is this even partially (which includes phrases like "Use X. See [link] how") an answer if every link it contains is dead? In all the above links it is not. We are left with (replacing the dead link text with "*nothing*"):

1. See the example in this link to see a use-case: *nothing*.
2. I did see a couple of PHP SDK's for SMS: 1. *nothing*, 2. *nothing*, 3 *nothing*.
3. See *nothing*. Here you will find your answer.
4. See *nothing* it tells you the whole story

What should I do with these answers then? Let them be?

Should I comment something like "It's better to include part of the resource you are linking to" that nobody will see and the author won't care about anyway (because it's *answer* cannot be deleted for that so his *precious reputation* is safe)?

Should I expect for those links to actually be dead in order to flag them (this means that I have always to check whatever the link is available and even then the link could disappear one minute later)?

Should I edit the answer myself to include the part of the resource in the post (but why would I spend time for someone that didn't have the will to take 1 minute of his life to do that himself?)?

Please tell me what I should do in this case. Should the above *answers* be deleted?

Comment: Related: [Can we get some consensus on what flag to use for link only answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers)

Comment: @Jeffrey, while these answers are indeed poor, they're all *accepted* answers. Deleting them has many implications that have to be taken into account (IMHO an accepted answer should never be deleted). You can downvote them and/or leave a comment like you're suggesting.

Comment: Downvote (this may be enough to toss it in the low quality review queue), edit, improve.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could always down-vote instead of insisting that moderators delete them, since - [as @KatieK pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190417/165455) - they are still answers (they become useless when the link dies, but are still answers while the link is alive). There's nothing wrong with flagging them, just be aware that moderators are people and some feel differently about which link-only answers actually are not an answer.

Also because of the way the flag handling system works, it might be possible in some cases that another user flagged as spam or something else, and the moderator has to choose whether to accept or decline all of the flags, rather than individually. They can also make mistakes: moderators are people.

Finally, if you've been flagging dozens of link-only answers today, moderators might have started declining them to encourage you to stop inundating them with this stuff and switch gears. I mean, in all honesty, some of these are 2+ year old answers. Why the rush to suddenly delete them all?

Oh, and I just realized from a comment that these are *accepted* answers, which further complicates things. If you are truly interested in making SO better and keeping it clean, and not just increasing your helpful flag count*, you could edit the answer to provide some useful context around the link. Nothing major but a sentence or two summarizing what can be found in the blog post can make the answer much more valuable. Or, as you suggested, add a comment prompting the author of the answer to add some context, and explain why.

**I'm not accusing you of this, btw.*

Comment: Why the rush to suddenly delete them all? Because I like to think that this website is *clean* and I help to keep it that way.

Comment: "You could edit the answer to provide some context around the link". I've explained why I don't feel like spending my time for someone that haven't spent his/her to make a good answer and earn reputation from it.

Comment: @Jeffrey then down-vote the answer.

Comment: For what? [Apparently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190416/not-an-answer-flags-declined-why/190418?noredirect=1#comment590148_190416) accepted answers cannot be deleted anyway so what's the point?

Comment: See @MichaelT's comment - it could end up getting into a review queue where someone else might be more willing to add context. Also a down-vote may spur the author to improve the post (if they understand, which they may not without a comment). People really don't like down-votes and will often try to prevent them.

Comment: Also, down-votes are one way for you to show the author and the community what you think about the quality of a post. Which type of bad answers *do* you down-vote?

Comment: Down-voted answers are additional motivation for the Answerer to update their answer.  Also &lt;evil&gt;if you add a new awesome answer, it will look better by comparison&lt;/evil&gt;.

Comment: Additionally, you stated above that your motivation is about the site. So maybe if you stop thinking about it in terms of "spending my time for someone" and think about it instead as "spending my time improving an answer" it won't seem like such a burden to do exactly what you're professing you want to do.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, are you suggesting that we (or at least I) should improve link only answers?

Comment: To be frank, I never know what to do with link-only answers.

Comment: I'm suggesting that if you're finding that you're spending time flagging a bunch of them, and then moderators are consistently spending time actively declining them, that a different approach may seem reasonable, yes. Down-voting poor quality answers is another approach I also suggested. You don't seem very open to either, so *shrug*.

Comment: @OldCheckmark I've found that it can depend on the site, the tag, the moderator, whether it's raining...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, 85% of those flags are accepted. So I think moderators are pretty happy about it. If they are not they only have to come in here and tell me and I'll happily stop. After all it's not me that have let people *elect* me because I promised I would have spent time for this website. Also, I've already told you (in the question) that I down vote them, but that doesn't seem to clean them up like I'd like for the above reasons.

Comment: Not always. But I took your question as: "I've flagged these link-only answers, and they're still there. What else can I do?" I'm trying to offer you suggestions for other options. I obviously can't guarantee that they'll always be more effective than a flag, but they certainly have the possibility of being more effective than a *declined* flag.

Comment: So till now you have suggested me: 1) to improve the answers myself (very wrong. do you want me to go there and explain why?). 2) downvote them (I already do). Am I missing something else?

Comment: I also explained why a flag that you think is valid may sometimes be declined. But no, I don't have any other magic answers for you. Maybe you can use voodoo to make the moderators involved in the above rejections bend to your wishes, and delete accepted link-only answers?

Comment: And I don't understand why improving the answer is "very wrong." Just because you can't be bothered to do it doesn't make it wrong. If you're interested in improving the quality of the site you wouldn't have such a negative attitude about it. I improve other people's posts all the time, and I already have all the badges so there is nothing in it for me except the satisfaction of improving a post. I'm not sure how that can hockey stick into "very wrong."

Comment: Why the sudden hostility and sarcasm? Meta is for discussion IIRC. We are here to discuss. And I'm discussing your answer because it's the one that I felt being the most in depth on of the two. I don't really expect things to change. In my personally limited experience it's actually quite the opposite. Things that are brought to meta rarely change anyway. I'm just trying to explain why your *options* are not doing what I think is the correct action: deletion. Why is it correct IMHO? Because it's the only action that can act as a deterrent for this kind of answers.

Comment: I offered you a couple of suggestions (which you've spit on) and I also took great care to explain to you why your link-only flags might get declined (which you have refused to comment on). What more do you want from me? What is your *actual question* (since the title and body go two different ways), and is it a question this community can answer?

Comment: "And I don't understand why improving the answer is "very wrong."" - Because we would be actually *encouraging* them this way. If people *know* that if they just paste a link someone come and will fix them for you why would I (generic user) even bother to write a good answer anyway?

Comment: @Jeffrey I'm talking about cases like the one you cited in the question. Most likely they are not going to get deleted because they have been accepted. So if you let go of the idea that they should be deleted for a split second, you'll see that you only have a few options: **(1)** improve the answer (this works *for* the site) **(2)** down-vote (this punishes the user, even though they helped the OP, and does not improve the site other than, maybe, but probably not, prevent the answerer from doing the same thing again) **(3)** do nothing (this helps nobody).

Comment: Yeah, right. Well, thanks for this discussion.

Comment: Why would you bother to write a good answer? Because you care about quality. Because a good answer is *better* for the OP (but a link-only answer might still be useful). Because good answers get more up-votes. Plenty of reasons. Stop being so concerned that some people get a bit of rep from crappy answers.

Comment: This website is 90% about reputation and meritocracy. When someone here tells me that "they don't care about reputation" it just makes me laugh. I personally try to write good answers because I want to get credit for it. I flag bad answers (even though I earned every badge I could on that) because I feel bored and I feel good at cleaning up a website I believe in instead of go playing Candy Crush.

Comment: @Jeffrey I have 80K on SO. Do you really think I care that I lose 1 rep when I down-vote a bad answer, or 2 rep when they pay me back? Do you think I cared when I had 2K or 20K? What this website is 90% about *for you* is not necessarily what it is 90% about for everyone else. Not faulting you for wanting to clean up, I'm again just trying to offer you suggestions of what to do when moderators don't agree with your reflexive way to perform some of those clean-up efforts, and give you some explanations as to why those flags might be declined. Those were the things you were asking for, right?

Comment: FWIW @Jeffrey, it's the quality of the site that attracted me. Not the rep system.

Comment: There are a lot of "awards" on this site that don't involve reputation. There are badges, there is the interaction, there is the fact that even the teachers learn things (including things they thought they knew that later turned out to be wrong), and there is also the fact that people come here because it's a much better-run site than any other forum I've been on. What exactly are you going to do in the real world, with the reputation you earn here? Why is that reward more valuable than any of the others?

Comment: You have clearly never read anything about how reputation systems *really* works. Do you think that this website would work without the reputation system? I seriously doubt so. "What exactly are you going to do in the real world, with the reputation you earn here?": just to make an example: I know of someone that has been contacted by Google for a job offer also because of their reputation in this website.

Comment: Someone offering a job solely based on reputation here is probably going to do a lot more vetting than just looking at your profile page. And in any case, if you post good answers and use your down-votes wisely, what changes about that? If your rep is 79K and you have a better interview at Google than I do, do you think they're going to pick me over you because I have 1K more than you?

Comment: Also please don't try to presume how much reading I've done or how much I understand this site.

Comment: "that has been contacted by Google for a job offer **also** because of their reputation in this website". For all that matters you could have also said that I don't have proof and that that story about Google could have been invented and you would have been probably right. The point is not what you can do in real life. Is that your effort is payed somehow that it won't be completely lost and forgot. People are interested in this: being awarded for things they do. And there are some very interesting psychological studies about this. Also I'll just stop here since we are going way off topic now.

Comment: @Jeffrey we got on this presumably because I said `Stop being so concerned that some people get a bit of rep from crappy answers.` If you think that the type of people who post link-only answers to gain rep are the kind of people who get job offers from Google (in part or in full) because of that rep...

Comment: And I'm not saying people aren't motivated by reputation - they absolutely are. But if they're using the site correctly, it quickly becomes a secondary motivator. At least in my experience.

Comment: @AaronBertrand _"down-vote the answer"_ -- you mean, **[downvote 24000 answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183709/165773 "as discussed in more details here")**?

Comment: @gnat no, that is absolutely not what I mean. If someone wants to try to clean up the whole site, have fun with that, but it's not what I'm condoning. What I'm talking about is down-voting these types of answers that you come across naturally in the regular use of the site.

Comment: @AaronBertrand what's the point then? How many link only answers one comes across _naturally_? few... few dosens... maybe whole freakin' _hundred_? how voting these down is supposed to make an impact on site readers who will still see these 24000 upvoted link only answers? oh wait that will be like 23900, big deal. With all due respect, that sounds like emptying the sea with a teaspoon

Comment: @gnat how many can each user possibly do? I edit a lot of posts to improve them, but they are a total drop in the bucket compared to all of the posts that go unimproved. Should I stop bothering?

Comment: @AaronBertrand my point is, unless one specifically focuses on link only answers, and unless these efforts have substantial support from moderators and SE team, there's little use of trying, in the face of that 24,000 number. No matter how [honorable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism) your intentions are, it will make no difference anyway

Comment: @gnat But I feel that killing or improving *new* link-only answers has a lot more net effect than going around finding 4-year old link-only answers and killing or
 improving them. Nothing is ever going to fix all 24,000 of those links, but if we can really slow down how we *add* to that number, I think the site is better off. Your current objection to my piecemeal approach seems to be, well we can't fix all of them, so let's fix none of them.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it's like nippin' off the leaves while keeping the roots. Whatever you do, next guys will come to that old, high-on-Google question, will stare at low effort link with 5... 10... 20 upvotes and think _hey that's the way to go, that's what they like here_. Laugh if you wish but I felt exactly the same when I arrived at SO... the notion of link only answers being somehow bad, is not widespread outside of Stack Exchange. I would say it's not known outside at all. These guys coming out of there, they think links are OK

Comment: @gnat ok so let's not do anything. *shrug*

Comment: @AaronBertrand [that's not the only option](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167953/165773)

Comment: @gnat ok then post an answer or link to a duplicate instead of just bashing my suggestion and implying in the process that trying to deal with it is hopeless.

Comment: @gnat: we're never going to support indiscriminate, context-insensitive deletion of answers featuring prominent links, and even if we were we could easily do so automatically rather than wasting folks' time flagging. I'm *honestly* perplexed as to why you would wish for anything else. Beyond that, your broken window argument is [inaccurate](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6aaka.png) - as I've [noted before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers#comment560991_183709). Please either back it up with data, or stop making it.

Comment: @Shog9 data is right there, in SEDE, all 24000 points of data

Comment: @AaronBertrand why would I? I like it when people are reminded of downvoting. I am just not comfortable that these are presented as a solution to a _systemic_ problem but oh well

Answer (score 14):

I declined two of those, so I should probably explain why. When you are flagging an answer as "not an answer" or "very low quality", you are asking for us to unilaterally delete content that someone has posted. We take this very seriously, particularly since those flagged and deleted answers [now feed into the review audit mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently/160755#160755). Generally, if there is some value at all to a primarily link-based answer, I won't delete it.

I'm concerned that in our desire to keep the site clean, we're losing sight of the forest for the trees. Do we absolutely need to remove every single link-based answer on the site? Are we helping to make the Internet a better place by removing links to relevant and potentially valuable resources?

A common argument against link-only answers is that they are strong candidates for rot as links go away. However, as I [commented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers/183676#comment560633_183655), a link may or may not go away at some point in the future, but if we delete all such answers we are *guaranteeing* that they will no longer be available. We might be causing the exact kind of information loss that we're seeking to prevent.

In all of these cases, the answers you flagged were accepted answers to the questions asked. That indicates that at least the asker found value in them, backed up by the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049242/what-is-the-typical-use-for-operator/6049319#comment6999796_6049319) of "Good reference, and now that I know the term for the operator, it makes googling much easier." I generally don't delete link-only accepted answers (in fact, I tend to only delete accepted answers when plagiarism or other shenanigans are involved), and [Bill agrees with me on this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143642/cant-link-only-answers-be-auto-deleted-instead-of-showing-up-in-the-review-queu/143648#143648).

As Shog9 points out in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers/183676#183676), a better way to approach these might be to leave comments asking people to expand on their answers or to bring some of the linked content into the body of the answer. If the linked content does go away, and they haven't fleshed out the answer, I'm perfectly fine with removing the now-worthless answer at that point.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Even though I completely disagree. I will slow down flagging and will avoid flagging accepted answers.

Comment: If that [same link only answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6049319/493122) was posted *recently* (and wasn't accepted, for sake of argument), would that be flaggable? I was under the impression that link-only answers fall below the standards of SE. I understand (not that I agree) that *old* link-only answers are given a wider berth, but what about recently posted link-only answers?

Comment: @Jeffrey - Just to be clear, we really do appreciate you taking the time to flag things for cleanup. I hope you don't think I'm being too critical of you here and in my previous comments, but the above is something I've been thinking about for a little while and wanted to write down. My attitude towards link-only answers has shifted a bit over the last year towards being a little more permissive after hearing a few people complain about answers they found useful going missing.

Comment: It would be nice if we could put answers "on hold" and spur the OP (or review queue) to improve them.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that is actually an awesome suggestion.

Comment: @Matt - As Anna points out in her answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183655/135615 , it may not even be possible to post such an answer today with the more stringent length requirements we have now. Even so, if there is utility in a link-only answer left today (and it isn't someone trying to drive traffic to their personal or company blog), I still like to leave a comment and ask them to flesh it out. With newer answers, you're a lot more likely to get people to come back and edit them into something better. I've seen this a few times in the last week alone.

Comment: @Brad: [Looks like it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17867218/444991). So as long as you see a comment from the flagger on the post, giving time for the user to tidy up his link-only answer, you're happy to unequivocally delete it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I do recall a feature request around here somewhere for the ability to place a temporary banner on an answer requesting expansion of the answer or editing for quality, but I can't seem to find it. Seems like that might not be a bad way to address this (and other issues with answer quality).

Comment: @Brad [is it this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188839/another-option-reviewing-low-quality-posts)?

Comment: consider a not so _"common argument against link-only answers"_ - these are telling readers loud and clear: link-only answers are welcome. Your reasoning about Not An Answer flag decline makes good sense to me though

Answer (score 9):

"Thanks!" or "I'm having this problem too" is certainly not an answer.  Link only answers are *answers*, even if they're not very good ones.

You can downvote these answers, and / or leave a comment suggesting beefing up the answer a bit.  It doesn't always work, but [sometimes it does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59324/327466).

Or you can add a better answer - one that includes and explains the content of the link.  Maybe you'll get well-deserved rep and badges for an awesome answer.

Also, look at the *question*. Maybe it could use a bit of editing for clarity, or maybe it's the question that needs to be deleted / flagged / close-voted.